# Создать список из другого списка по условию

Tags: python, list

Имеются два списка:

```
l1=['0023', '0024', '0025']
l2=['IMG_0023_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0023_550_20.tif', 'IMG_0023_670_30.tif', 
'IMG_0023_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0023_840_20.tif', 'IMG_0024_475_30.tif', 
'IMG_0024_550_20.tif', 'IMG_0024_670_30.tif', 'IMG_0024_715_10.tif', 
'IMG_0024_840_20.tif', 'IMG_0025_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0025_550_20.tif', 
'IMG_0025_670_30.tif', 'IMG_0025_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0025_840_20.tif']
```

Далее что должно происходить:

берется элемент из первого списка (0023)
во втором списке берутся файлы, где есть 0023 и помещаются в список.
В конечном итоге должен получится список списков:

```
[['IMG_0023_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0023_550_20.tif', 'IMG_0023_670_30.tif', 
'IMG_0023_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0023_840_20.tif'],
['IMG_0024_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0024_550_20.tif', 
 'IMG_0024_670_30.tif','IMG_0024_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0024_840_20.tif'],
['IMG_0025_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0025_550_20.tif', 
'IMG_0025_670_30.tif', 'IMG_0025_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0025_840_20.tif']]
```

Как это сделать, товарищи??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

алгоритм

1. проходите по списку l1
2. проходите внутри 1) по списку l2
3. ищете подстроку l1 в строке l2
4. если находите - помещаете элемент l2 в новый список
5. проверяете выходной список на дубликаты и удаляете их (или сразу множество `set` вместо `list` используете)

Comment: Именно так и делал.
Получалась какая-то фигня.
Задал вопрос здесь. Вы написали именно так,как я и делал.
Удалил код и написал заново.
Всё заработало.
Магия!